# Where to find a specific LaTeX symbol

Tags: latex, symbols

The symbol I'm looking for can have several names, I want to use for "contraction" (of a measure and a set).

It should look like the lower left half of \square, that is, like \llcorner but bigger. I've found different packages containing the symbol, but none of them seems to be compatible with amssymb.

Does anybody know where to find such a symbol? Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) to recognize symbols name, and then just google for it.

Comment: That tool is awesome, I was about to suggest the same +1

Comment: Great tool! Unfortunately, it does not find the symbol.

Answer (score 4):

I would begin with the [Comprehensive LaTex Symbols list](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/) from CTAN. Are you looking for something like \niv ? (check out page 60 of the symbols-letter.pdf.)  It's in the [Natural mATHematics notation package](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/nath.zip) form CTAN.

More on `\niv` from the [nath guide](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/nath/nathguide.pdf), pg 9:

> Nath introduces \vin and \niv as names of the im-
>   portant symbols ‘_ |’ and ‘| _ ’ not included in any standard math font.

Comment: I have the Comprehensive list on my desk :); unfortunately is not very searchable. \niv seems to be what I'm looking for, but including the nath package results in loads of errors: "Leaders not followed by proper glue". I'll see if I can fix this.

Comment: Turns out that nath is not compatible with AMS document classes, or at least clashes with the use of AMS multiline equation environments

Comment: Take a look at the nathguide: http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/nath/nathguide.pdf  On page 16, it specifically talks about using `\usepackage{amssymb,nath}` .  There is also a quote 
*math mode commands must be those of Nath* - (if using amsmath).  This implies you may have to use the nath versions of some constructs when using this package.  It also says *"A number of math commands have been redefined; `\old{command}` often provides access to what `\command` was before Nath redefined it"*.  Significantly, the *math* environment is disabled in nath, which might be a problem.

Comment: Nath uses two distinct math modes. The single dollar sign
$ invokes the *in-line* mode. The double dollar sign $$ as well as other math environments invoke the *display* mode.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same problem! Here's my solution:

```
\def\ellerovesciata#1#2%
 {\vbox{\hbox to#1pc{\vbox to#2pc{\vfil} 
  \hfil\vrule}\hrule}}

\def\ctr
 {\ellerovesciata{.5}{.5}}
```